# if (str == "Привет") Правильно ли? Java. Как сравнивать строки

Tags: java

Работает, но не так как надо.
При вводе Привет должно выводить "И тебе привет :3"

[image: Скриншот окна с кодом и с консолью внизу]

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует разобраться как работает `==`, если сравниваемые объекты не примитивные (а `String` это не примитив), то сравнение происходит по ссылке, а т.к. у Вас разные по факту объекты, то и в консоли у Вас выводится как я предполагаю что-то там про воспитание, если вы попробуете поменять все на `int`, и будете выводить "привет" допустим если пользователь ввел "1", то это сработает, а так необходимо использовать `equals()`, но по стандарту он так же сравнивает ссылки, поэтому Вам еще необходимо будет и переопределить этот метод. Про переопределение ищите. Да, и еще кое что, не надо в подобных случаях пожалуйста присылать скрины, вставляйте код, так будет проще скопипастить его в случае чего и внести изменения.

Прочел еще раз вопрос, и понял, что не совсем правильно на него ответил, это говорит о том, что даже желания нету особого вчитываться в скриншоты. Вам в любом случае я рекомендую использовать метод `equals()`, для этого изучите его подробнее

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Fastow если ответ Вам помог, и является правильным - отметьте его пожалуйста как Верный